# Настройка доступа к MySQL с докера

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть докер с Apache+PHP+MySQL+OpenSSL, нужно настроить докер таким образом что бы все подключения были через docker, а на сервере остались: БД и тело сайта, но сколько инструкций в интернете, не пойму, куда копать дальше, что уже сделано:

1. Настроен докер, висит на порту 80;
2. Установлен том, docker run -it -p 80:80 --net="host" --privileged -v mSQL:/var/lib/mysql/demo_ehealth apache2_ufw_mysql_php_iit_ulimit /bin/sh;
3. С помощью команды  docker volume inspect mSQL  выяснил место расположения каталога /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/mSQL/_data;
4. В _data скопировал тело сайта и базу данных.

Что дальше делать не знаю, буду благодарен уточняющим советам что делать дальше, я так понимаю нужно создавать виртуальный хост для Апач, но как узнать где в докере примонтирован этот каталог? И как прикрепить управление к БД, надеюсь что не нужно создавать IP, достаточно только будет указать порт MySQL, но как его узнать порт и IP?

Answer (score 1):

1. mysql и apache лучше запускать в разных контейнерах.
2. проще использовать docker-compose

файл ./.docker/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ${SRC_PATH}:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT}:80
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASS: ${DB_PASS}
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/mysql
```

файл ./.docker/.env

```
COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION=TLSv1_2

SRC_PATH=../website
WEB_PORT=80

MYSQL_DATA_DIR=../mysql-data
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
DB_USER=test
DB_PASS=test
DB_NAME=db_test
```

файл ./.docker/php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./php/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/001-front.conf

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash appuser && usermod -a -G www-data appuser && \
    a2ensite 001-front && \
    a2dissite 000-default && \
    a2enmod rewrite

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

файл ./.docker/php/apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /var/www/html/web>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www-error_log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

файл ./website/web/index.php

```
<?php
$host = getenv("DB_HOST");
$dbname = getenv("DB_NAME");
$user = getenv("DB_USER");
$pass = getenv("DB_PASS");
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT NOW() as curtime', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$res = $stmt->fetch();
echo "now=".$res['curtime'];
```

задаем в .env файле нужные значения, 
выполняем cd .docker && docker-compose up -d --build

при открытии страницы в браузере - отобразится html-страница с временем в БД mysql